# How to change the image that has been clicked [react-router v4]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am using **react router v4** for routing. Link is applied in the image. When that image is clicked(if it is active), i want to change that image.

Here is the code to show the concept of what i want

```
class PrivateServiceType extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('context', this.context.router);
    let image = isActive ? 
      <img src={IconHouseSelected} alt="apartamentos" className="img-responsive" /> :
      <img src={IconHouseNotSelected} alt="apartamentos" className="img-responsive" />
    return (
        <div className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 serviceImg">
            <Link to="/apartamentos">
              {image}
              <h4>APARTAMENTOS</h4>
            </Link>
          </div>
      )
}

PrivateServiceType.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store `currentUrl` as a state object and assign that as the `src` of the `img`. Put a `onClick` handler on the img to toggle the `currentUrl`.

```
class PrivateServiceType extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        iconhouseUrl = 'notselected.png'
     }

    this.toggleIcon = this.toggleIcon.bind(this);
   }

  render() {
    console.log('context', this.context.router);
    return (
        <div className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 serviceImg">
            <Link to="/apartamentos">
              <img src={this.state.iconhouseUrl} alt="apartamentos" className="img-responsive" onClick={this.toggleIcon}/>
              <h4>APARTAMENTOS</h4>
            </Link>
          </div>
      )
   }

  toggleIcon(){
     if(this.state.iconhouseUrl === 'notselected.png')
         this.setState({iconhouseUrl:'selected.png'})
     else
         this.setState({iconhouseUrl:'notselected.png'})
  }

}

PrivateServiceType.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

The `iconhouseUrl` state variable holds the url and the `toggleIcon` function handles the change which is bound to the `onClick` handler of the `img`

In accordance with your comment here is a route sensitive way

```
<Link to="/apartamentos">
          <img src={(location.pathname === '/apartamentos' )?'houseselected.png':'houseunselected.png'} 
           alt="apartamentos" className="img-responsive"/>
          <h4>APARTAMENTOS</h4>
</Link>
```

What this does is compare the current path (contained in `location.pathname`) with the condition and accordingly sets the icon.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I dont think this is a reliable way, though. Because i have used router to route the different form. There are 3 image/icon (apartment, car rent, experience ). When apartment image is clicked, form for apartment is shown and similar to other. The solution you provided works but when i click on car rent, the image of apartment is shown selected but it should not.

Comment: Also after being image selected, when i again click on it, it toggles to non selected. That is why i tried to use router context to track if it is active or not.  if its active show the selected image otherwise non selected image.

Comment: Updated the answer with a route sensitive way. I've shown only for apartments but you can use it for the other two routes as well by modifying it.

Comment: I have not used previous version react router where i could do <Route path='/apartamentos'> and can use this.props.path. Sorry i did not understand how can i use this.props then in react router v4?

Comment: using this.props.path i get undefined. I used location.pathname === '/apartamentos' ? 'houseselected.png':'houseunselected.png' i got an error of Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

Comment: location.pathname worked for me. Thanks a lot for your support. Can you please edit this.props.path to location.pathname === '/apartamentos' ? I will mark it as answered.